# AUDIT TRIAL IN APEX; to audit changes a user makes to the source table lds_placement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_placement
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE
    ON lds_placement
    FOR EACH ROW
    ENABLE
DECLARE
    v_user                                  VARCHAR2(30);
    v_date                                  VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
    SELECT USER, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
      INTO v_user, v_date
      FROM DUAL;

    IF INSERTING
    THEN
        INSERT INTO audit_trial(
                                placement_id,
                                new_name,
                                old_name,
                                user_name,
                                audit_date,
                                audit_operation
                               )
             VALUES (
                     :NEW.plt_short_desc,
                     NULL,
                     v_user,
                     v_date,
                     'INSERT'
                    );
    ELSIF DELETING
    THEN
        INSERT INTO audit_trial(
                                placement_id,
                                new_name,
                                old_name,
                                user_name,
                                audit_date,
                                audit_operation
                               ) -----line 16 is here.statement ignored
             VALUES (
                     NULL,
                     :OLD.plt_short_desc,
                     v_user,
                     v_date,
                     'DELETE'
                    );
    ELSIF UPDATING
    THEN
        INSERT INTO audit_trial(
                                placement_id,
                                new_name,
                                old_name,
                                user_name,
                                audit_date,
                                audit_operation
                               )
             VALUES (
                     :NEW.plt_short_desc,
                     :OLD.plt_short_desc,
                     v_user,
                     v_date,
                     'UPDATE'
                    );
    END IF;
END trg_placement;
```

I get this error:

> Error at line 16: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: From [ask]: "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague". "urgently" is not the best way to post a question

Comment: You insert 5 values in 6 columns

Comment: thanks!! fixed the error.

Comment: sorry for my choice of word "urgently" thanks

Comment: am trying to add loop statement to the audit trial so that the when a user makes changes to any column in the source table lds_placement it will be auditted. but from my query this trigger is for only one column plt_short_desc i want for all column. please can you help with the query. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_placement
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON lds_placement
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_user varchar2(30);
v_date varchar2(30);
BEGIN
SELECT user, TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') INTO v_user,v_date FROM dual;
IF INSERTING
THEN 
INSERT INTO audit_trial(placement_id,new_name,old_name,user_name,audit_date ,audit_operation)
VALUES(:old.placement_id,:NEW.plt_short_desc,:OLD.plt_short_desc,v_user,v_date,'UPDATE');

ELSIF DELETING 
THEN
INSERT INTO audit_trial(placement_id,new_name,old_name,user_name,audit_date,audit_operation)
VALUES(:OLD.placement_id,:NEW.plt_short_desc,:OLD.plt_short_desc,v_user,v_date,'DELETE');

ELSIF UPDATING 
THEN
INSERT INTO audit_trial(placement_id,new_name,old_name,user_name,audit_date ,audit_operation)
VALUES(:OLD.placement_id,:NEW.plt_short_desc,:OLD.plt_short_desc,v_user,v_date,'UPDATE');
END IF;
END trg_placement;
```

I have made changes and it's working.